# how is that the jquery function can start with '$'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, api, object

if you declare a function in javascript, you can't use the '$' character in the name, so how is that jquery is able to do so?  For example:

```
function myFunction() {
    $("#h01").html("Hello jQuery")
}
$(document).ready(myFunction);
```

but if i declare a function as so:

```
function $(a){
// do something
}
```

javascript shows an error?

Comment: bc `$` returns a javascript object - a jquery object.

Comment: it also uses `global['$']` or `window['$']`.

Comment: Au contraire! You _can_ use `$`. It is a valid name for JS variables/functions. They introduced it back then for compatibility reasons with server-side languages.

Comment: daniel a.white - yes i get that $() is a jquery function returning a jquery object, but my question was how can you name a function as '$'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
var $ = function(){
    // do something
};
```

and you won't get an error.

Comment: ur absolutely right and got the point of my question, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

From the specification,
https://es5.github.io/#x7.6

```
IdentifierStart ::
    UnicodeLetter
    $
    _
    \ UnicodeEscapeSequence
```

`$` is fine as a character in the name.

Demo, using the code in the question: http://jsfiddle.net/q02go7dd/

Comment: A link to a (quasi-)normative reference: +1.

Answer (score 0):

$ is a short-handed alias for JQuery object itself.

So when you type,

```
$("#h01").html("Hello jQuery");
```

you are calling JQuery constructor with parameter "h01".

It's like declaring a function called dave and giving it an alias ß and calling it like that.

```
dave("h01");
```

Answer (score 0):

$ is fine :

```js
$myFunction = function(){ alert("hello"); }

$myFunction(); // alerts "hello"
```

Comment: but by itself is not...so how is jquery able to use $ by itself?  edit:  nvm, i just tried var $=function(){} and it worked.

Answer (score -2):

Jquery is a wrapper which runs over javascript. In spite of using javascript large syntax, Jquery offer small syntaxs which is easy to use.

In Jquery $ sign return Jquery object.